# Current month (number) + year (number)

Tags: javascript

How do I output the current year and month (in numbers) in javascript?

getUTCMonth() logs: getUTCMonth is not defined

getUTCMonth() logs: getMonth is not defined

Comment: That's probably because your object is not a `Date`, show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this ?

```
var date = new Date();
date.getUTCMonth();
date.getUTCFullYear();
```

Comment: I did now, thanks :) Haven't messed with js date before

Comment: @mowgli so you dont want it as a number like you asked ?

Comment: @Dwza well getFullYear() and getMonth() returns number only, not string !

Comment: This outputs numbers and is fine

Comment: hmm.. than i had a wired problem :D i had to use Number  somewere when i used it because the result was a string....

Answer (score 1):

you could do it like

```
var date = new Date();

var day   = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year  = date.getFullYear();
```

**Attention**

`date.getMonth()` starts with `0` and goes to `11` so you have to add `+1`

Answer (score 0):

Month:
`new Date().getMonth()`

Year:
`new Date().getFullYear()`